# Windows Hello for Business (forced authentication)

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We have an application registered with single sign-on in Azure AD and have implemented step-up authentication using "Authentication Context" and "Conditional Access Policies".

The Conditional Access Policy is registered with Windows Hello for Business (WHfB) only in Authentication Strength so that we can guarantee that the user has authenticated with WHfB for some specific areas of the application.

It works perfectly when we challenge the Azure AD OIDC with the authentication context and the user will receive an error if a WHfB authentication cannot be completed.

However, when we "force re-authentication" by using "max_age=0" or "prompt=login" as parameter in the OIDC request, the user is prompted for password and the user will be redirected to the default password + MFA authentication flow, thus not satisfying the "Authentication Strength" of WHfB only.

I have attached screenshots from the flow below.

[image]

[image]

The user can click "Sign in with another account", click "Other ways to sign in" and select "Use Windows Hello or a security key". That is impractical and difficult to explain to end-users.

Does Microsoft support any hints for selecting a specific authentication method or is there a setting in Azure AD that can help us here? It seems the problem is only when forcing re-authentication.